# How to assert if particular strings are present using contain in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a div element like below,

```
<div>first, second, long text</div>
```

I want to check if this div element contains text 'first' and 'long text'.

To check for only string I use like below,

```
cy.get('div').should('contain', 'first');
cy.get('div').should('contain', 'long text');
```

The above two works. but now instead of writing two statements I want to combine into one statement.

Meaning I want to check if div element contains strings 'first' and 'long text'. So I have tried like below,

```
cy.get('div').should('contain', 'first, long text')
```

This fails because there is 'second' string between first and long text and hence fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's nothing wrong with two checks

```
cy.get('div')
  .should('contain', 'first')
  .and('contain', 'long text');
```

or you can use a regex instead

```
cy.get('div')
  .contains(/^first(.*)long text$/)
```

where `^` is start-of-string, `$` is end-of-string, and `(.*)` means any number of chars in between.

A third option is to use the pseudo-selector `:contains()`

```
cy.get('div:contains("first"):contains("long text")');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.and()` to create the next assertion:

```
cy.get('div').should('contain', 'first').and('contain', 'long text')
```